# AppleScript: Move files via drag and drop

Tags: finder, applescript

I need to create workflow that allows the user to drop files onto the application and then have those files moved to a particular folder to be processed based on their file type.

So far, I've not got past the drag, drop, and move part!

```
on open theDroppedItems
    repeat with a from 1 to length of theDroppedItems
        set theCurrentDroppedItem to item a of theDroppedItems
        tell application "Finder"
            set folderSpool to folder "Spool" of desktop
            move a to folderSpool
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

When I do the drag and drop, I get:

> Handler can’t handle objects of this class. Finder got an error:
>   Handler can’t handle objects of this class. (-10010)

I tried `item` instead of `a`, but that gave me the same error.

It's been a long time since I used AppleScript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line of *code* from:

```
move a to folderSpool
```

To:

```
move theCurrentDroppedItem to folderSpool
```

In your *code*, `a` is an *integer*, indexed `from 1 to length of theDroppedItems`, so you were trying to move an *integer* (which of course you can't) not the file, which is `theCurrentDroppedItem`.

Comment: Brilliant! As I said, it's been a while since I did this.